# DPDK UDP packet transmission issue - error UDP length greater than IP payload length

Tags: rhel7, dpdk

We have recently upgraded to DPDK 18.08 version.
After upgrading to the latest version observing issue with UDP packets transmission error for few packets.

No issue observed while transferring UDP packets with size 28 bytes and 48 bytes.
I tried to print the packet length calculation in my program just before sending it out to the Kernel using rte_kni_tx_burst.
The packet length calculation seems correct to me.

```
1.) 
size_udp:48
sizeof(struct udp_hdr):8
size_ApplMsg:40
udphdr->dgram_len:12288
m->data_len:82
size_ip:68
l2_data_shift:14

2.)
size_udp:28
sizeof(struct udp_hdr):8
size_ApplMsg:20
udphdr->dgram_len:7168
 m->data_len:62
 ip->total_length:12288
 size_ip:48
l2_data_shift:14

Packets with UDP size 736 are not getting transmitted to the receiving end and getting dropped.

3.)
 size_udp:736
 sizeof(struct udp_hdr):8
size_ApplMsg:728
udphdr->dgram_len:57346
 m->data_len:770 
size_ip:756 
l2_data_shift:14
```

Also MTU is set to 1500 in my program. So it shouldn't be an issue to transfer 736 bytes UDP data which is less than 1500 bytes MTU.

I tried to increase the kernel buffer size but that didn't help.
netstat -su  -> output shows 0 send/receive buffer errors.

What has changed in DPDK 18.08 with respect to UDP packets?
Please suggest if I need to consider tuning udp, offloading udp traffic to resolve this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: So why UDP len is always bigger than 1500 bytes? Did you also check the UDP checksum?

Comment: The UDP len is 736 bytes < MTU 1500 bytes. I am calling rte_kni_tx_burst to send this packet out and the return Value of thi API call is successful.But tcpdump trace shows error : "BAD UDP LENGTH 736 > IP PAYLOAD LENGTH ] Len=728.Whether hardware offloading is causing this issue ?Any offloading flags needs to be set?

Comment: I mean this len "udphdr->dgram_len:57346" and this len "ip->total_length:12288" Why they both are bigger than 1500?

Comment: ip->total_length = rte_cpu_to_be_16(size_ip) ; udphdr->dgram_len = rte_cpu_to_be_16(size_udp) . ip->total_length and udphdr->dgram_len are big endian forms converted from  16-bit value CPU order( size_ip and size_udp).

Comment: The packet dump taken before sending to KNI looks proper. Is there a way I can attach those packet dump and tcpdump traces in this forum ?Moreover it will be helpful if you could suggest some debugging steps to analyse if the packet is getting dropped at NIC or at the Hardware. I tried to run dpdk-pdump.But it gives me error.# ./dpdk-pdump -- --pdump 'port=0,queue=*,rx-dev=/tmp/rx.pcap'
 Mempool creation failed: Cannot allocate memory